Not able to insert data in postgresql database with docker and symfony 7
I have Symfony postgresql on docker, Installed a database,
Using adminer as ui for the database.
As entities (classes/ models) I have three tables: User, UserProfile and PostEvent.
While testing on Homepage which is defined as route: "/" . I have created a method when the homepage is reached it will create a default user that I created and send it to the database to be inserted.
class MainController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/', name : "new_app")]
    public function index(EntityManager $manager): Response
    // public function index(): Response
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail('PinkWOop@email.com');
        $user->setPassword('12345678');

        $profile = new PostEvent();
        $profile->setTitle("Test Data");
        $profile->setDescription("Data testing here!");

        $email = $user->getEmail();
        // $prf_id = $profile->getUserUniq();
        
        $manager->persist($profile);
        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();

        // return new Response($profiles, 200);
        return $this->render(
            'main/index.html.twig',
            [
                'user' => $email,
                'profile_id' => $profile->getDescription()
            ]
        );
    }

As seen within the codeblock I render it withh twig, also installed a profiler package that shows which queries are running/executed on a page.
Everything seems fine and get a satus code of 200 on the page, and within the profiler application  the query is processed and "COMMITED" .
Within the database, the table PostEvent is still empty,
Also tried inserting data in other entities User and the UserProfile but also that did not work.
I tried configuring the Entity class of PostEvent and UserProfile.
When I created these entities, I created them to be nullable,
I tought If I made them not nullable somehow it would inser the data,
this didnt worl.
Then inside the "var/log/dev.log" file the following showed:
- php.DEBUG: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /app/vendor/symfony/validator/Resources/translations/validators.ro.xlf [] []       <- X1000

- doctrine.INFO: Connecting with parameters array{"use_savepoints":true,"driver":"pdo_pgsql","host":"database","port":5432,"user":"test","password":"<redacted>","driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":[],"dbname":"martial_arts_db","serverVersion":"16","charset":"utf8"} {"params":{"use_savepoints":true,"driver":"pdo_pgsql","host":"database","port":5432,"user":"test","password":"<redacted>","driverOptions":[],"defaultTableOptions":[],"dbname":"martial_arts_db","serverVersion":"16","charset":"utf8"}} []

- doctrine.DEBUG: Executing query: SELECT 1 {"sql":"SELECT 1"} []

- doctrine.INFO: Disconnecting [] []

- deprecation.INFO: User Deprecated: Relying on non-optimal defaults for ID generation is deprecated, and IDENTITY results in SERIAL, which is not recommended. Instead, configure identifier generation strategies explicitly through configuration. We currently recommend "SEQUENCE" for "Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQLPlatform", when using DBAL 3, and "IDENTITY" when using DBAL 4, so you should probably use the following configuration before upgrading to DBAL 4, and remove it after deploying that upgrade:  $configuration->setIdentityGenerationPreferences([     "Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQLPlatform" => ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_SEQUENCE, ]); 

I not sure what the issue is with PostEvent not inserting Data in the database, But I do see that the User Class is likely deprecated. I googled this and saw a possible solution of using "composer update", I tried this and clear the application cache and clean out docker volumes, images, container.
Unfotunatley It did not change the Issue with inserting data
I am really exited to work on this project, and also my first symfony and postgresqk.
So I need the help.
If there are any questions left, please ask?
github: linkToProjectGitHubPage
UPDATE:
I edited the docker-compose.yaml
I did find outt if I use the following command:
symfony console dbal:run-sql 'SELECT * FROM post_event'
That it does show something in the database...
The data I posted :D .....
id | title    | description | created
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 | Test Data | Data testing here! 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
2 | Test Data | Data testing here!

But how come I dont see it back in the database.. I dont see it in schema 'public' within the adminer panel Does anyone has a clue?
But when I search user command:
symfony console dbal:run-sql 'SELECT * FROM user'
I see one column, with two rows, containing ont he first 'user' and second row 'test'
 user (column name)
 - - - - - - - - - - 
 test (1)


I excepted to see a email and password, But it looks like the user I use to log into the adminer panel.
I am now looking how to fix this, I might have to customly create the User, because within the log.. I keep seeing that the User class is deprecated.
But still weird I dont see the data in the database.
And I also changed the following:
database:
  volumes:
    - db: /var/lib/mysql/data:rw

to:
database:
  volumes:
    - db: /var/lib/postgresql/data:rw

Also when I open database port inside the browser http://localhost:5432/.
It shows that the page is not working and in the resource tab it says failed error empty response.
When I to adminer panel url-port http://localhost:8000/ I can see the adminer panel. Not sure if databases url path suppose to not give a response.
I hope to be able to create (,update, read and delete) data and see it back inside the adminer panel or other database managment panel (docker container). And continue with the project I am working on.

It may help if you add your use statements for the controller as well as your Entity files (or at least the id and relation fields  definitions). Also please mention how you created the DB schema, did you use the doctrine:schema:create console command? What do you get when you run doctrine:schema:validate?

I've never used postgresql or docker but this line just looks wrong: https://github.com/Ted-bot/backend_ma/blob/main/src/Entity/User.php#L11C1-L11C29 Why do you have literal backticks in the table name string?

@ArleighHix Thank you very much for the. Very sharp notice about the literal backticks, This was done automatically when I used Symphony command symphony console make:user, I then used Command and composer require symfony/security-bundle

@ArleighHix
I tried to import use DateTimeInterface inside the UserProfile Entity but did  not found the defnition of it (use key CMD and click on 'use DateTimeInterface' on macbook. I have also Added 'use use App\Entity\UserProfile  to the import in the the User entity.
I have the database installed by just doen docker-compose up —build -d and then symphony console make:migration and finally symphony console doctrine:migrations:migrate to setup the database.

@ArleighHix
I just tried adjusting what you just pointed out. But unfortunately If I remove the literal backticks, I get to see the following error:



@ArleighHix
And I still don’t see any data within the database wiht the other adjustments I juyst made. But thank you very much for looking out

I did find outt if I use the following command:
symfony console dbal:run-sql 'SELECT * FROM user'
That it does show something in the database...
The data I posted :D .....
But how come I dont see it back in the database..
I dont see it in schema 'public' within the adminer interface
Does anyone has a clue?

what does your connection string to the database look like? also trying to access http://localhost:5432/ in a browser will not work, postgres is not using the HTTP protocol.

I did not figured out why I could not see the data on the adminer panel.
but I have connected my visual s. code IDE, to the database by installing vs code extension: Database Client after loggin in I can see the data.
I tested the database connection by inserting a new row with the 'Database client extension', and it worked. It is all visible and manage able.
So I am going to continue without using adminer to manage the data.
I want to Thank @ArleighHix trying to support and others looking it to this.
